# Knockout subscribe to observable object

Tags: knockout.js

I have an object:

```
{ model: settings: { "FirstName": "Joe", "LastName": "Bloggs" } };
```

in my view model I make settings an observable:

```
this.Settings = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(model.settings));
```

Which makes `FirstName` and `LastName` observables too.

In my view I bind by doing:

```
<p data-bind="text: Settings().FirstName"></p>
```

to read a value from `Settings` I do:

```
`this.Settings().FirstName()`
```

The problem comes in when I want to subscribe when `FirstName` OR `LastName` changes.

I know I can do `this.Settings.FirstName.subscribe...` but that's painful once you get more than two things you're observing.

Is there a way to do `this.Settings.subscribe...`? or should I be using a custom binding?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the plugin below to help me deal with such situations:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

Here's a simple usage example:

```
 this.Settings.watch(function(root, trigger){
     var newValue = trigger();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using, computed observables, you can automatically update whenever any of these dependencies changes. For example, FullName will get updated when either Firstname or LastName changed.

```
 this.Settings().FullName =  ko.computed(function() {
    return this.Settings().FirstName() + " " + this.Settings().LastName();
});
```

borrowed from [KnokcoutJS.com](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Note: I will work little more to make viewmodel little cleaner.

Comment: Yep thanks for that. But I'm trying to find a way of subscribing to changes without listing all the child properties because the Settings object has about 20-30 child properties. Get's very painful when you have list each child property. Also if you delete/rename a child property everything breaks so if you could subscribe from the parent level that would be ideal :)

Comment: This wasn't mentioned in your question. Anyway, you can do some custom binding like Ryan did for dirtyFlag (link below). 

The concept is to compare initial state of the object (before mapping) to the current state of object (by converting to JSON).

Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which lets you take plain JSON objects and convert them to full view models.

Basically it converts every member on each object into an observable:

```
var data = { "FirstName": "Joe", "LastName": "Bloggs" };
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Then you could bind this viewmodel to your html a bind properties straightaway like this:

```
<p data-bind="text: FirstName"></p>
```

This is a small example, I only mapped a plain object, but you can also achieve more complex mappings if you wanted to convert nested objects like the one in your example. There is more information about this on the documentation.