# Knockout subscribe to inner object of observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have an observable to bind HTML elements:

```
{ model: processing: { "errorMsg": "save Failed", "msgType": "info" } };

this.processing= ko.observable()
```

Data-bind as:

```
<p data-bind="text: processing().errorMsg"></p>
<p data-bind="text: processing().msgType"></p>
```

Another observable to hold value keyed by user.

```
self.sessionUserData=ko.observableArray();

//Computed Observable : Contains user selected UI data to save in DB.

self.UserSelectedData=ko.computed(function(){
                var obj = {
                editableMetadata : self.editableMetadata,
                sessionUserData : self.sessionUserData };
                    return obj;
                },null,
                {           
                deferEvaluation: true
                }
            );
```

I wanted to subscribe errorMsg so that i can update sessionUserData  observable accordingly as below.

```
self.processing.ErrorMsg.subscribe(function (obj) {             
                    self.sessionUserData().totalErrMsg=obj;
                });
```

Above subscription do not work at all.
Is there a way to do this.

Note: There are other such observable which is similar to processing, whose task is to bind with  html element only. The idea is to populate sessionUserData observable with UI selected data so it can sent as ko. `tojson(UserSelectedData)` to server.

Comment: ErrorMsg isn't an observable...

Comment: I tried like this as well but not working. self.processing.subscribe(function (obj) {             
                    self.sessionUserData().totalErrMsg=obj.errorMsg;
                });

Comment: You can only subscribe to observables, even if you were to subscribe to the parent object `processing`, then you'd only get updates when the parent object changes. Meaning you wouldn't get updates if a non-observable property (`errorMsg`) inside it is updated. Which objects are being updated? It might help to provide us a scenario.

Comment: @Stanislas: I tried like like as well 'self.processing.subscribe(function (obj) { self.sessionUserData().totalErrMsg=obj.errorMsg; });'  but execute while loading the page not when '<p data-bind="text: processing().errorMsg"></p>' is updated with some other value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout subscribe to observable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180653/knockout-subscribe-to-observable-object)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still very badly put together.
I've taken all your code blocks and corrected the JavaScript errors into something that works. I'm hoping that this will:

- Help you find the problem on your own.
- Demonstrate how you can ask a better question, using a snippet like the one below.

Note: each comment in the snippet was something I had to fix, simply to create something that would run.

```js
var ViewModel = function(model) {
  this.processing = ko.observable(model.processing); //initialized this observable with the provided model, since your template is assuming that processing will always have a value.
  this.sessionUserData = ko.observableArray();

  var self = this; //Added since, you're using it inside your subcribe method.

  this.UserSelectedData = ko.computed( //This seems compleltely unnecessary for your example.
    function() {
      var obj = {
        editableMetadata: self.editableMetadata,
        sessionUserData: self.sessionUserData
      };
      return obj;
    },
    null, {
      deferEvaluation: true
    }
  ); //Removed an extra bracket here

  this.processing.subscribe(function(obj) { //Removed "ErrorMsg" since: the casing was incorrect, but also "errorMsg" is a string, not an observable, so you cannot subscribe to it.
    self.sessionUserData().totalErrMsg = obj;
  });

  this.updateProcessing = function() { //Added this method to handle the click on the "Update"-button.
    this.processing({ //Note how I'm not using the following, as that wouldn't work: this.processing().errorMsg = ...
      errorMsg: Math.random(),
      msgType: Math.random()
    }); //I used Math.random to demonstrate different values when updating.
  }
};

var model = {
  processing: {
    "errorMsg": "save Failed",
    "msgType": "info"
  }
}; //Removed "model: ", as that would be an invalid object.

var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
p {
  background-color: #ddffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

errorMsg:
<p data-bind="text: processing().errorMsg"></p>
msgType:
<p data-bind="text: processing().msgType"></p>
<button data-bind="click: updateProcessing">Update</button>
```

Comment: my requirements is similar to this post. [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180653/knockout-subscribe-to-observable-object)